# Is this yucky thing scat or slime mold?

Tags: scat-identification, mold

I took a picture of this in mixed wooded hills in Oregon in winter. I thought it might be animal scat and was wondering what type of animal, but I asked someone who thought it might be slime mold, at which point I remembered I didn't notice a smell from it.

Can anyone identify this from the picture?

Surroundings:

[image: surrounding ground & leaves]

Close-up:

[image: close-up]

Comment: That's definitely poop, not mold.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Thanks. I've seen more since I asked, and still curious what it is from - deer, bear, dog, raccoon, skunk, coyote...

Comment: One way to identify bear poop is that it has bear bells in it, and it smells like bear spray.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking through all of the pages of Google Image search slime molds, I was unable to find anything that resembled the brown stuff in the above images. There is a list of the [Slime Molds of the Cascade Mountains of Oregon and Washington](http://science.halleyhosting.com/nature/cascade/fungi/myxomycetes/myxomycetes.html) and nothing in that looks similar either.

I would say that it is runny scat from an unknown animal.

Comment: +1, but I am surprised that you did not continue to exmine the pictures of [runny animal scat](https://www.google.com/search?q=runny+animal+scat&tbm=isch&imgil=9dO-37J43g0meM%253A%253B6HRdfRce9kVVUM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.bear-tracker.com%25252Fblackbearscat.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=9dO-37J43g0meM%253A%252C6HRdfRce9kVVUM%252C_&usg=__wT38fNNOE0OZJp2Hc-WSia8XKdY%3D&biw=1113&bih=619&ved=0ahUKEwi0w4Clzc_SAhXGQyYKHZIXAGwQyjcIUA&ei=B4jEWPSjDcaHmQGSr4DgBg#imgrc=9dO-37J43g0meM:)

Comment: @ab2 It you want to examine pictures of runny animal scat in great detail, knock yourself out :)

Comment: This could be anything - even dog (who often get mucusy poop due to their anal glands... what a mental image for a Monday morning...)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like poop with Toxoplasmosis' a protozoan infection to me. As I've had toxoplasmosis i know what it looks like. It kind of looks like white flag worms at one stage and at a other stage it looks much like clear, yellow, green or beige liver flukes with eyes. They're not actually eyes however. Its my brain anthropizing them.